# Extract 2 numbers from a string to populate textboxes vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

The project is a calculator that displays the math operations in a listbox (i.e. the listbox would show something like 1+2=3).  The calculator is completely functional and working correctly.  Now here is the problem.  I have been asked to extend the functionality of the calculator to be able to modify listbox entries when selected. When a listbox item is selected I need to populate two textboxes with the two numbers in the math operation.  So if I selected "1+2=3" then I would have to populate the first textbox with 1 and the second with 2 so that they can be modified.  I am assuming this needs to be done using regex, but I have zero experience with it and just can't get my head around this one issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Know it's not regex but should do the trick (with a little refractoring for your purpose):

```
Dim k As String = "2+3=5"
Dim p = k.Split("+=".ToCharArray())
Console.WriteLine(p(0))
Console.WriteLine(p(1))

'p() contains the split out parts of your expression.
```

Comment: Chris that is awesome, thank you.  Would I use a select case statement to add the other three math operators?

Comment: think just try adding them into the Split statement like this:
Dim p = k.Split("+-*/=".ToCharArray())

Answer (score 0):

To split 12+13=25 :

```
(\d+)([-+*/])(\d+)=(\d+)
  ^ Matches 12 (In capturing group1)

(\d+)([-+*/])(\d+)=(\d+)
         ^ Matches + (One of -, +, *, / operator) (In capturing group2)

(\d+)([-+*/])(\d+)=(\d+)
               ^ Matches 13 (In capturing group3)

(\d+)([-+*/])(\d+)=(\d+)
                     ^ 25 (In capturing group4)
```

Comment: Thank you Andie for this excellent explanation of your regex! I am going to try and implement it! Thanks again!